# Javascript scope issue, inside an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, scope

Sorry I couldn't be anymore specific with the title.

I'm building a web-site (personal), which displays different content to the user depending on the query string that is used in the url.

e.g. `page=home.html` would display `home.html`

The websites Javascript is wrapped inside an object, with each value containing different data, some pseudo code:

```
(function(){
    var wrapper = {
        init: function(){
            //Runs on document ready
            this.foo();
            this.nav.render();
        },
        foo: function(){
            //Some functionality goes here for the website, e.g. Display something from an API
        },
        nav: {
            //Functionality to handle the navigation, has different properties
            config: {
                //Contains the config for nav, e.g. page names + locations
                dir: '/directory/to/content/',
                pages: {
                    page_name: wrapper.nav.config.dir + 'page_value'
                }
            },
            render: function(){
                 //some code
            },
            routes: function(){
                 //some code}
            }
        }
    };

    $(function(){
        wrapper.init();
    });
})();
```

My problem is that I'm trying to prepend the `dir` value to each of the `page` values (inside the object where the pages are defined), expecting to get the output of (in this pseudo code case) of `directory/to/content/page_value`, but instead `dir` is undefined when I'm trying to access it, I've tried the following to achieve what I want:

- wrapper.nav.config.dir + 'page_value'

I've been playing around with the last 30 minutes trying to find out what I'm doing wrong, and even thought about hard-coding the URL in for each page.

The reasoning for wanting to do this is that my local development server and web host have different directory structures, so I don't want to re-write the URL's each time I want to develop + publish. As for why everything is wrapped inside an object, I thought it would be easier to maintain this way.

Hopefully the answer is simple and it's just an amateur mistake / lack of understanding.

Comment: Where is the line of code `wrapper.nav.config.dir + 'page_value'`?  It isn't in your above example.

Comment: It's what I've used to try and access the dir property, with no success

Comment: I've also edited the question to where I tried to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you can't refer to a variable that is being defined in that very definition.

So, inside the definition of `wrapper`, you can't refer to `wrapper`.  And, inside the definition of `config`, you can't refer to `config` either and so on.

The usual design pattern for solving this is to initialize as much as you can in the declaration of your data structure and then do the rest in `.init()` when you can freely access all of it.

Comment: OK, assuming you don't want to know about syntax typos (there are still more in your question), I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, as far as syntax typos, on the actual source I don't get any errors in the console, so I asssume it's working as intended.

Comment: @Daniel - Next time please try to post code that doesn't have a bunch of syntax errors.  When you do that, we can't tell whether those errors are what are causing the problem or not and you're less likely to find the real answer you want.  Anyway, glad you finally got your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change the first two lines to:

```
var wrapper = null;
(function(){
   wrapper = {
```

Otherwise, the wrapper is a local variable to your anonymous function.

Comment: The reasoning for wrapping everything in an anonymous function was that I thought defining global variables was bad, still, making the changes, I still get a `wrapper` is undefined.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem.  If the OP needed to access wrapper outside of the anonymous function, this might be one solution, but that isn't part of the question at all.

Comment: @jfriend00: "but instead dir is undefined when I'm trying to access it, I've tried the following to achieve what I want" I assumed this is because wrapper is actually undefined while used in link or something.

Comment: @Daniel, where do you use wrapper actually?

Comment: Look at the code they have in their answer now.  It won't compile because of the problem mentioned in my answer.  They are trying to access `wrapper` inside the definition of `wrapper` (which is inside the self executing function).  The question was edited since you may have seen it.

Comment: @Krizz - the question has been edited to show where wrapper is being accessed (in the definition of it).

Comment: Yes, I agree. The code will definitely stop to be interpreted at the definition of `page_name`. Upvoting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're still busy defining the wrapper when you ask for its value, which is why it's still undefined.

The code below fails too:

```
var x = {
    y:"1",
    z:x.y
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
//...
init: function(){
    //Runs on document ready
    this.foo();
    var config = this.nav.config;
    for (var page in config.pages) {
        config.pages[page] = config.dir + config.pages[page];
    }
},
//...
```